# How to run a stored procedure without changing the as of date parameters using autosys

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, ssis, autosys

```
Execute METADATA.Runprocess
    @p_PROCESS_NAME = 'WEEKLY LOAD'
    ,@p_AS_OF_DATE = = '9/20/2016'
    ,@p_SOURCE_SYSTEM = '2'
    ,@p_ETL_ORDER = 'ETL'
    ,@p_TYPE_LOAD = '1'
    ,@p_TIME_FRAME = 'W'
    ,@p_IS_AUTOMATED = 0`
```

The above stored procedure needs to be run every week on a Tuesday. Currently I am running this stored procedure manually having to change the `@p_AS_OF_DATE` every week. I would love to automate this using autosys. Where would would be the best place to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new job via SQL Agent and schedule it to run every Tue.

As for `@p_AS_OF_DATE`, inside TSQL task of that new job, you can declare a new date variable and set it to `GETDATE()`. Then you can pass the variable to SP call.

Comment: But wouldn't that require me to manually enter a date every time to that variable? I am trying to avoid any manual intervention.

Comment: No, it will be dynamic. "declare @today date = GETDATE()" - "@today" will be the date when the job is running.